# How to write to any address with any data?

Tags: origen-sdk

A lot of the Origen protocol plugins offer only top level register read and write methods, which requires one of the input arguments to be a register object. If i want to just write to a location that's neither a defined register or memory location, i.e. i just want to do a write to an address with a data, how do I do that please?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to write data and are not bothered about tracking the value or needing to do bit-level read/store operations, then all Origen read/write_register methods should accept a value in place of a register object, as long as you supply the address:

```rb
dut.write_register 0x1234_5678, address: 0x4000_0010
```

A better approach however, is via the read/write memory API, this is equivalent to the above:

```rb
dut.mem(0x4000_0010).write!(0x1234_5678)
```

When you call that API it will generate an anonymous register object in the background to keep track of the value and to provide bit-level access. In other words, you get the same capabilities as if you had defined a register at that location.

For example, if you need to check what you have written there:

```rb
dut.mem(0x4000_0010).data    # => 0x1234_5678
```

You can read/store at bit-level, and also sync if you are using an OrigenLink or OrigenSim compliant debug environment:

```rb
dut.mem(0x4000_0010)[15..0].read!(0x5678)

dut.mem(0x4000_0010)[31..16].store!

dut.mem(0x4000_0010).sync
```

Memory can also be accessed via a sub-block with a local address, however there is only one memory object and this will return the same register object as for the corresponding global address. For example, say in this case that we have been writing to an IP block that has a base_address of 0x4000_0000 within the DUT.
Within the Origen pattern source code for that block, you can use relative addressing:

```rb
# From within the IP-level model/controller
mem(0x10).write!(0x1234_5678)

# Accessing the same location via a global path
dut.mem(0x4000_0010).data  # => 0x1234_5678
```

By default, `mem` returns 32-bit register objects and the address must be aligned. The width can be changed on a per-DUT basis:

```rb
dut.memory_width = 16

dut.mem(0x4000_0010).size   # => 16
```

Finally, the sync method will accept a size argument which corresponds to the number of memory locations to read out:

```rb
(byebug) dut.mem(0x4000_0000).sync(10)
40000000: FFFE0080
40000004: 00005555
40000008: 00000000
4000000C: 00000000
40000010: 12345678
40000014: 00000000
40000018: FFFFFFFF
4000001C: FFFFFFFF
40000020: FFFFFFFF
40000024: FFFFFFFF
```